# Is the Phoenix compiler tools project still alive?

Tags: llvm, cocor

I'm looking around for a modern tool chain to help in developing a small programming language/DSL. I would like to explore [Phoenix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_%28compiler_framework%29) from [MS Research](https://connect.microsoft.com/Phoenix/content/content.aspx?ContentID=4513), but it looks like a dead project. Is that the case, and should I be looking elsewhere?

I'd like to target CIL with Phoenix, but would definitely consider LLVM (or other) if that was the best tool chain to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Phoenix is dead. I am not a Microsoft employee though.

LLVM is being very actively developed, but it may be an overkill for a small DSL, especially if you want to target a managed runtime that has its own JIT compiler.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, That's how it appears. Can you suggest a good compromise alternative? Preferable in the MS tech stack?

Comment: for what it's worth, the DSL may morph into a general purpose language, and it's a recreational project anyway, so overkill is not a problem ;-).

Comment: As we are a JVM vendor and our consulting business revolves around Java, C/C++, and (surprise!) Modula-2, I have to admit that I am almost totally ignorant of what is going on around CLR. That said, there is a handful of Mono-compatible compilers (http://www.mono-project.com/Languages) - perhaps you could fork one of those so as to not reinvent the wheel?

Comment: _To the best of my knowledge, Phoenix is dead._

It will reborn.

Answer (score 1):

[Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com) is a development kit for implementing languages on the .NET platform. The Mono stack also has some tools to help writing out IL assemblies - I'm thinking of [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) in particular.

Another approach would be to output C# from your DSL. That would give you a higher-level 'target' language for your DSL.